# Need help w/ Regex expression - match anywhere

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression to match on one of the following words (county or county of) **anywhere** in the statement. Additionally, I want to match on the entire phrase that is contained in the brackets, anywhere in the statement.
In the examples below, I would want to match on 'COUNTY' AND '(formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)'. It doesn't matter where these 2 tokens appear in the statement.

Ex:

1) NORFOLK COUNTY (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)

2) COUNTY   NORFOLK (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)

My expression so far:

```
(county of|county)\s*\(.*\)
```

This will match #1, but not match #2. I don't know how to express in my regex that '(.*)' should be matching anywhere in the string additionally to the word match of 'county' or 'county of'.

Comment: That will not work, the examples can get more complicated, I just pasted couple easy examples to simplify. My rule is extended so that other words can match like district, or district of.

Comment: If you want to match the entire phrase if "county" is inside it, try `(.* county .*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
String input = "NORFOLK COUNTY (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)";

String output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(county of|county)|(\(.*?\))", "", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine( output );
```

[snippet here.](http://ideone.com/KZcm06)

Explaining:

```
(county of|county)     # one of the options
  |                    # OR
(\(.*?\))              # anything between brackects
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, how do I include the brackets in the match (so text and brackets should match).

Comment: nvm, I figured it out: (?=.*(\(.*\))). Thx for your help I think this should work.

Comment: No, I just want to match county, and the entire expression in the brackets including brackets. So the final expression that matches is: (county of|county|district of|district|city of|city)(?=.*(\(.*\)))  . But, when I use it in my Regex.Replace() function, to replace the match occurrences w/ white space it only replaces the first occurrence which is 'county', the text '(formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)' is not replaced. Do I need to do something different for Regex.Replace() ?

Comment: The regex matches fine and the sample works but I use the expression w/ the Regex.Replace() method like this:  Regex.Replace('NORFOLK COUNTY (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)', '(county of|county)(?=.*(\(.*\)))', '', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase). The Replace() method only replaces 'County' match, nothing else. I need it to replace both matches in the groups.

Comment: 2nd example has problem. Expression fails if you have only "COUNTY NORFOLK". It will not match. But the requirement is that it should match on "COUNTY" or any "(fsdfasdfasdf)"

Comment: @ActiveX. I've updated. I thought it should match brackets only if `county` were found... but I corrected it

Comment: Unfortunately, now it doesn't handle the case "NORFOLK COUNTY", after replace runs I still see "COUNTY". I only want to see "NORFOLK" in: "NORFOLK COUNTY (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)", "NORFOLK COUNTY", "COUNTY NORFOLK  (formerly RM Haldimand-Norfolk)"

Comment: @ActiveX. I tested your three example above and all them returns just `NORFOLK` to me.

Comment: It appears, I did not refresh your snippet,- Your expression seem to work, many Thanks! I will keep testing but should do the trick.

Comment: @ActiveX. You can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/gN6pB3/2) how the regex works... It finds the occurrences to be replaced by empty string